# Comparing textBox1.Text and textBox2.Text

Tags: c#

so i have this code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string str;
    public string str2;
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        str = textBox1.Text;
        str2 = textBox2.Text;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Material Name Please.");     
        }

        if (str == str2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Materials are equal.");
        }

        else if (str != str2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Materials don't match.");
        }
    }
}
```

i think you'll guess what i'm trying to do here.. can you tell what's wrong with it? i started a couple of days ago so forgive my lack of knowledge.

Comment: what are you trying to compare with two `textbox`?

Comment: You need to include only the relevant parts of your code within your question, empty methods won't be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are initialiting those strings only once in the constructor instead of in the click-event handler. You can also use properties to map the controls with the strings which makes the code more readable and robust:

```
// use meaningful control/variable names
string Material1 
{
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
    set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}

string Material2
{
    get { return textBox2.Text; }
    set { textBox2.Text = value; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Material1)) // handles also multiple spaces
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Material Name Please.");  
        // return; <-- perhaps?   
    }

    if (Material1 == Material2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Materials are equal.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Materials don't match.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably a good time for the op to learn about references and values, the other alternative of course would be for the op to update `str` and `str2` in the empty text_changed events I edited out

Comment: It isn't required, but a return statement after the messagebox in the null check test might be an improvement. Assuming that OP doesn't want to test equality if material1 is null.

Comment: @failedprogramming: i'm sure that this can be improved in many ways but it's not a bug to continue here. I also wanted to concentrate on the essential (i've already used properties to map the strings with the controls).